# Error when trying to renew Visual Studio Community Edition license

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Community Edition 2013. My trial ran out recently and I'm trying to renew it by logging in. A window pane comes up for me to sign in and I enter my credentials, however I get the following script error:

Line: 4
Char: 16405
Error: Object doesn't support this property or method
Code: 0
URL: https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/_static/tfs/20150123T002517/_scripts/TFS/Loader.min.js

After some rudimentary searching, it seems as if I'm missing a library. Has anyone experienced the same problem and knows which part of the code it's referring to? I don't want to go on a mad updating rampage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been running into this problem for months. I do development on Virtual Box machines running XP, because it is small and easy to copy, and I have gotten this problem on some of the machines and not others. I thought it had to do with window updates, but I have that turned off, and I am still getting the problem on machines that just worked a few days ago. Unfortunately with XP you can't update anything or even go back to a previous version of IE.

Comment: As Abundance didn't mention using a VM or XP, this appears to be more of a *possible* cause of the issue rather than a solution.

Comment: Actually, I am running this Windows 7 machine on Virtualbox. I was thinking that I have to install all the updates, but I felt like that would've taken too long and wasn't sure if I wanted to have updates for products I didn't use. If somebody knows exactly which update, that would be appreciated. Otherwise, I'll just try all the updates and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it was the virtualization software itself. I'm actually using vmware not virtualbox (mix-up in the comments). Incidentally, vmware just released an update today and after installing it, I was able to log in. 
By the way, it could've been the log-in itself. After the update, microsoft visual studio didn't even ask me to validate the software, but went straight to the ide. I saw by my user id, an exclamation prompting me to sign in, whereupon I was able to validate my install.